# Cannot Connect MongoDB from Meteor

Tags: mongodb, connection, meteor

I need to connect `MongoDB` from Meteor. I have installed `MongoDB` using the command prompt. After that, I have tried to connect to the `MongoDB`. This time I got an error.I didn't have any idea about this. Does anybody have suggestions as to what to do?

Error :

```
E:***\MongoDB\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Mon Jan 20 12:56:37.648 Error: couldn't connect to server *.*.*.*:27017 at src
/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Meteor has MongoDB support built in... Read the docs on [Collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections) and [deploying with a custom `MONGO_URL`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying).

Comment: How to set custom MONGO_URL for Windows?Can you please give me guidance i had tries but not set.@Cuberto

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways depending on how whether or not you've deployed it or not.

If you've run `meteor deploy some.url.com`, you can access your site from a new terminal window by inputting `meteor mongo some.url.com`.

If you're simply run `meteor` to get your app running (not deployed), open a new terminal, `cd` to the directory of your project, and enter `meteor mongo`.

Comment: How to do this for windows System?@mjkaufer

Comment: What is your question? How to deploy on the Windows system totally independent of Meteor servers or how to access the mongodb? Because the code above allows you to access the mongodb.